# A class of generalized Integrals involving polygamma functions

Tags: definite-integrals, riemann-zeta, pi, zeta-functions, euler-mascheroni-constant

I recently came across some nice integrals and I have a few questions about them: You may have heard of the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$ and if you did so, you may know the following integral:

$I_1=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\ln(x) dx=-\gamma$

But what happens if you somehow change this integral a little bit? If you replace $\ln(x)$ with $\ln^2(x)$, you get an suprising answer.

$I_2=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\ln^2(x) dx=\gamma^2+\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

This already looks quite weird. Why would the square of $\gamma$ appear right here. And what has this to do with $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. When I've tried to generalize this even more things got even weirder.

$I_m=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\ln^m(x) dx$

If you now evaluate this with $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ you get answers involving integer powers of $\gamma$ and the Riemann Zeta function: $\gamma^m, \zeta(m)$. Intuitively, why would powers of $\gamma$ pop out right here? They seem to appear nowhere else. And what has this to do with the zeta function? Is there a general formula for $I_m$, where $m$ is an integer or even a real number? I really have no idea.

I'm thanking every one who replies.

Comment: Let $~n!=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x^n~e^{-x}~dx.~$ Then $I_m=(n!)^{(m)}_{n=0}.~$ See [gamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), [digamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), [trigamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function), and [polygamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) functions.

Comment: Hint:  For $m=1,2,3,...$, try evaluating the Mellin transform $\mathcal{M}_x\left[e^{-x} \log ^m(x)\right](s)$ at $s=1$.

Comment: See also [functional equation of the Riemann $\zeta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Riemann's_functional_equation).

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the integral representation of Gamma
$$
\int_0^\infty  {e^{\, - \,t} t^{\,x} \,dt}  = \Gamma (x + 1)
$$
and taking the derivative wrt $x$
$$
{\partial  \over {\partial x}}\int_0^\infty  {e^{\, - \,t} t^{\,x} \,dt}  = {\partial  \over {\partial x}}\int_0^\infty  {e^{\, - \,t} e^{\,x\ln \,t} \,dt}  = \int_0^\infty  {e^{\, - \,t} t^{\,x} \ln t\,dt}  = \Gamma '(x + 1)
$$
and the second derivative
$$
{{\partial ^{\,2} } \over {\partial x^{\,2} }}\int_0^\infty  {e^{\, - \,t} t^{\,x} \ln t\,dt}  = \int_0^\infty  {e^{\, - \,t} t^{\,x} \left( {\ln t} \right)^{\,2} \,dt}  = \Gamma ''(x + 1)
$$
and so forth.

So what you are looking for corresponds to $m!$ times the coefficient of $x^m$ in the power expansion of $\Gamma (x+1)$.
$$
\int_0^\infty  {e^{\, - \,t} t^{\,x} \left( {\ln t} \right)^{\,m} \,dt}  = \left. {\Gamma ^{\,\left( m \right)} (x + 1)\;} \right|_{\,x\, = \,0}  = m!\left[ {x^{\,m} } \right]\Gamma (x + 1)
$$

These can be expressed as linear combination of the coefficients of the expansion of $\ln \Gamma (1+x)$, i.e. in terms of $\psi ^{\,k} (1)$, and thus in terms 
of $\gamma ,\; \zeta(k)$.